# Query for unique record on basis of status

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help in writing the sql query for finding the record on the basis of status. I created a table using this query:

```
CREATE TABLE inglogs (id int, mobileno int(10), status varchar(10));
INSERT INTO inglogs (id, mobileno, status)
VALUES
(1, 1234, 'fail'),
(2, 1234, 'fail'),
(3, 1234, 'success'),
(4, 2345, 'success'),
(5, 2345, 'success'),
(6, 4326, 'fail'),
(7, 4327, 'success')
```

I want to query from the above table where and get distinct mobileno like `1234,2345,4326,4327` with its status like if there is any success with that mobileno , it should return that record with id and status, also if there is not any success for any mobile (`in my case it is 4326`) then that should also be visible in in the executed query.

eg I want some thing like this:

```
+---+  +--------+  +----------+
|id |  |mobileno|  |  status  |
+---+  +--------+  +----------+
|3  |  |  1234  |  |  success |
|5  |  |  2345  |  |  success |
|6  |  |  4326  |  |  fail    |
|7  |  |  4327  |  |  success |
+---+  +--------+  +----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an aggregate with a conditional:

```
select max(id) as id, mobileno,
       (case when sum(status = 'success') > 0 then 'success' else 'fail' end) as status
from inglogs
group by mobileno
```

see sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e71e7/3

Answer (score 0):

You can crudely do this with :-

```
SELECT MAX(id), mobileno, MAX(status)
FROM inglogs
GROUP BY mobileno
```

Although this is relying on success being greater than fail (ie, if you had a status of 'unknown' as well it would fail)

Or using a subselect:-

```
SELECT MAX(id), mobileno, CASE WHEN sub1.mobileno IS NULL THEN 'fail' ELSE 'success' END AS status
FROM inglogs a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT mobileno, COUNT(*) FROM inglogs WHERE status = 'success' GROUP BY mobileno) sub1
ON a.mobileno = sub1.mobileno
GROUP BY mobileno
```